# How to cancel switchmap chain in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, switchmap

The following use of `switchMap`...

```js
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)

  // First switchMap
  .switchMap(i => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(i, 'is even, continue');
      return Rx.Observable.of(i);
    }
    console.log(i, 'is odd, cancel');
    return Rx.Observable.empty();
  })

  // Second switchMap
  .switchMap(i => Rx.Observable.timer(0, 500).mapTo(i))

  .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

... produces the following output:

```
0 is even, continue
0
0
1 is odd, cancel
0 // <-------------------- why?
0 // <-------------------- why?
2 is even, continue
2
2
3 is odd, cancel
2 // <-------------------- why?
2 // <-------------------- why?
4 is even, continue
.
.
.
```

I would expect the following output:

```
0 is even, continue
0
0
1 is odd, cancel
2 is even, continue
2
2
3 is odd, cancel
4 is even, continue
.
.
.
```

I expected that the first `switchMap` would cancel everything downstream, every time it returns, which I guess was incorrect.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Tip: Make your code runnable and it will make it easier for others to try to solve your problem

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks, didn't know it worked with console output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that returning an empty observable does not cause it switch to the new observable, that is the second switchMap never gets called.

A **really hacky** solution would be to return a magic value that you can ignore later

```js
const CANCEL = {};
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)

  // First switchMap
  .switchMap(i => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(i, 'is even, continue');
      return Rx.Observable.of(i);
    }
    console.log(i, 'is odd, send CANCEL observable');
    return Rx.Observable.of(CANCEL);
  })


  // Second switchMap
  .switchMap(i => Rx.Observable.timer(0, 500).mapTo(i))

  // Filter out cancelled events
  .filter(i => i != CANCEL)
  
  .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So that works, but for my use case it's a bit inconvenient -- I have a sequence of maybe 8 switchMaps, so all of these would have to check for that case. I'm wondering if there's another operator that I should be using instead...

Comment: I accepted it, because in the end I also think that's probably the only way. I'll have a look and will try to see if maybe my approach with switchMap to this problem is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I know, it's not great, but the point of switch map is that it cancels when a new observable is emitted. In your case, you don't want to emit a new observable, so it won't cancel it. I think you need to implement a custom operator doesn't filter out empty observables.